# How to show "updated" posts within a chronological stream/feed?

Tags: user-expectation, activity-feed, chronology, newsfeed

What's the best way to show updated (edited or commented on) posts within a chronological feed of posts? This is essentially a categorized Twitter-like feed. So, naturally, users can comment on them.

I was thinking about having a separate "updated" feed that sits on top of the chronological feed for posts which are currently not showing in the chronological feed. But then again, I'm not sure how I would indicate whether the post or comment has been edited or has a new comment.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two possibilities - first, you could flag (visually mark) updated posts within the stream to indicate that they have been updated:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2Diz2.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Or you could use the update date of a post as the key in sorting the posts in chronological order (i.e., move them to the proper place as if they had just been posted).  This is probably the better option.

Finally, you could do some kind of combination (placing them in updated chronological order but also marking updated posts).

Comment: I like option 2 as well. I wonder if I can go with a hybrid approach of indexing the feed by last_updated and visually marking the post with "NEW" and then changing it to "UPDATED|EDITED". Could that be considered the best of both worlds?

Comment: @PaulKonova It depends on what the needs of your users are.  If they just need to know if something is updated, that would work well.  If it's more like an SE site (where it is important to know the original post date as well as when it was edited), you might want to show both.  I do like the idea of ordering by update date and also showing an indicator.

Comment: i would do the combination as suggested, to avoid the confusion of something looking like a repost, maybe show both posted and updated times separately too

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to elevate posts that have been commented on or updated since the original post, essentially using the date of latest activity as a way of sorting rather than by the original post date. This appears to be the model that LinkedIn uses, or used at some point, although I'm not sure how they're doing it presently. It strikes me as a much more natural way of surfacing posts that are active as opposed to digging through a list of old posts within a separate post sub-category.